# Why was this question edited after 4 years?

Tags: discussion

Why was [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133566/who-sent-ser-barristan-the-pardon-for-jorah-mormont) edited after nearly 4 years?

What was the purpose?

It does not seem to serve any purpose what so ever?

What was the reason?

Comment: I won’t add an answer because Mith’s already covers the reason for my editing it.

Comment: I will note though that there is no rule against editing old posts and we shouldn’t discourage it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, So why edit a question that is 4 years old other than to bring more attention to it?

Comment: For the reasons given below, also because of its score it wouldn't be shown on the homepage so would unlikely get anymore attention; this meta post gave it more than my edit did.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, Ok, edit this question as it has the same issues. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126726/why-did-chewbaccas-bolt-not-kill-or-knock-down-kylo-ren

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, should I send you a list of questions that have `edit` in them?

Comment: I edit questions as I come across them if they warrant one or if I'm doing another edit on that post. The amount of questions with "edit" or "update"  etc. in is going to be large. The main reason for editing this was the alt text which is something me and a few other users are going through and editing in as part to help the site's accessibility.

Answer (score 11):

The post was edited to remove noise, such as the "edit" markers, as well as to add alt text for the images contained in the question.

Including "edit:" in posts on Stack Exchange is generally highly discouraged; as posts are supposed to be a repository of information - akin to Wikipedia - including noise like "Edit:" or "Thanks!" is discouraged and people are encouraged to edit it out.

Adding image descriptions and alt text to images helps make that post accessible to people who either can't see images or are using a screen reader.

Please don't roll back useful edits.

Comment: I would also add that I think some of the changes were because of a failed Common Mark upgrade?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage, why bother with a question that is 4 years old? I have a very well received question that has up-votes that has the same `edit` in it , but it is not edited. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126726/why-did-chewbaccas-bolt-not-kill-or-knock-down-kylo-ren

Comment: @KyloRen: 
^_^ Looks like someone got to it. Just adding my own two cents, I'll occasionally go on a wiki walk of related questions that look interesting, and fix errors I run into in the process.